# Google Sheets Match Any Text

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets, I have 2 columns (A and B) of text and I'm trying to set up conditional formatting to identify partial duplicates for when these 2 criteria are both met:

- Text in A exactly matches with any other cell in A

and

- Any of the individual words in cell B match any of the words in any other cell in B

So, if A2 = "target.com" and B2 = "Big Bonus"

I want it to flag any other cells where A = "target.com" and B = "Bonus Donuts" or "Biggest Exciting Bonus Ever" (because "Bonus" is identified as the duplicate) or "Exciting Big Day" (because "Big" is identified as the duplicate).  I need it to be case-agnostic.

Nothing I have tried has even come close to working, so I won't include any of it here.

Sample Data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DO-0uJRf6MOJ7fJiza5MAmFNIqpCwJ4WMH28j6wp22w/edit#gid=0

Comment: The most efficient way to receive help will be if you provide a link to a sample spreadsheet that includes some realistic starting data. Otherwise, you are expecting the volunteer contributors here to create such data themselves, which is a deterrent to even getting started. If you choose to share such a link, be sure when creating the link that you select "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor" as the permission for the link.

Comment: Also, think through the full process and share as much about it as possible. I see potential problems given only what you've shared thus far. For instance, lets say you've got target.com, walmart.com and cvs.com throughout Col A, and there are matches for each between "Big Sale", "Summer Sale", "Summer Clearance", "Clearance Sale", "Biggest Sale of the Summer". Then potentially many, many rows will be highlighted. But how is that helpful, as there would be no distinction between brands or what the repeated target words are? And words like "of" and "the" would also flag as repeats, etc.

Comment: In addition, while "big" can be found in "biggest," "biggest" cannot be found in "big." This would be hard to control for. And then you have potential for things like "pet" to be found in "carpet," which isn't really a repeat. This would require a LOT of work and many controls to be in place.

Comment: Here is a link to a sample data sheet:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DO-0uJRf6MOJ7fJiza5MAmFNIqpCwJ4WMH28j6wp22w/edit#gid=0

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far, Erik. I understand that this may be infeasible.

To clarify, Col A must match exactly, and Col B must look for any partial matches, but complete words only so that "big" would not count as a match for "biggest".

Answer (score 3):

I've added a new sheet ("Erik Help") to your sample spreadsheet, with the following custom CF rule applied to the range A3:B ...

`=AND($A3=$A$1, REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER($B3),SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(LOWER($B$1))," ","|")))`

`$A3=$A$1` should be self-explanatory.

For the rest, you see I used `LOWER` to make the comparisons caps-agnostic. I applied `TRIM`, just in case you accidentally added any spaces into the B1 string and then just replaced remaining spaces with the pipe symbol, which is interpreted by `REGEXEXTRACT` as `OR`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want partial word matching (Big in Biggest), try this in the conditional custom formula:

`=and($A3=$A$1, regexextract(" "&lower($B3)&" "," "&substitute(lower($B$1)," "," | ")&" "))`

Comment: I was just coming back here to modify my post answer to account for this. Thanks for the inclusion.